# asp.net hidden redirect with direction url

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7, iis-7.5

How to do it:
When you access a certain page (like a folder), you can view information specific user, for example:

```
www.page.com/user001
```

Opens the default page www.page.com/userinfo.aspx in which that user get "user001" and display certain information. And the user see www.page.com/user001

I can do this with asp.net or IIS7?
something like subdomains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding the URL Rewrite Module to IIS.  Check this out
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can store the URL Rewrite rules in the web.config file. For example:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>

****(Your URL Rewrite Rules)****

            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But if it's not possible for you to store it in web.config due to security or maybe for some performance issues, then you can store the URL Rewrite Rules in IIS.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use routing in **global.asax** file at **application_start** event instead of rewrite the url also this will redirect every this to the profile page